# Grouping a grid using knockout-kendo

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

Using the knockout binding syntax in knockout-kendo, is it possible to define how the data should be grouped?   Ideally I'd like to disable the user from grouping and perform the grouping via the binding (or perhaps I will need to create a binding to do this?)

**Update:**

This seems to work fine if I define my property as a kendo.data.DataSource

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: response,
    // group by the "category" field
    group: { field: "category" }
});
```

Best I can tell, it doesn't appear to me like the knockout-kendo library supplies a hook to feed additional optional parameters to the datasource that it creates for you...   So there is no way to supply the "group" modifier to a non-kendo.data.DataSource that you pass in via the simplified, or options syntax.

Comment: What are you using as the data in your binding? A `kendo.data.DataSource` or a `ko.obsrevableArray`. Because default grouping can be only configured for a `kendo.data.DataSource` or you need to manually group your data in a format what the kendogrid expects...

Comment: it's an ko.observable, and I'm binding via knockout-kendo.  What kind of format will kendoUI interpret as grouping?  Currently the javascript object is flat, but I could easily change that.

Comment: I am taking a look at this: http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-framework/data-source/datasource-remote-grouping.aspx   looks promising...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use a `kendo.data.DataSource` directly as your data (but in this case I think you should) then one possible (altough kind of hacky) solution is to use the `widget` option in your binding.

When you are specifing a `widget` observable property KO-Kendo will set its value with the created Kendo widget.

```
<div data-bind="kendoGrid: { data: items, widget: widget }"> </div>
```

Then you can subscribe on the widget change event and set the grouping on the datasource:

```
this.widget = ko.observable();

this.widget.subscribe(function (value) {
   value.dataSource.group({ field: 'category' });
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kznC3/).

Comment: Ahh fancy :)  I think I prefer just newing up the datasource as I think it's less hacky.  Hopefully knockout-kendo could be updated to include this functionality.. perhaps something like data-bind="kendoGrid: { data: items, data-options : { group : { field: 'category' }}}"

Comment: Yeah there is already a hook called `ko.kendo.setDataSource` what you can also use for this. Somehow like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kznC3/1/ but this is a global hook so it used in every ko-kendo binding so you need to carefull what you write there and properly handle all the error cases.

Comment: Thanks, that's Perfect! :)  Not ideal to modify the library in such a way but definitely the result I was looking for.

Comment: The `ko.kendo.setDataSource` was meant to be overridable: from the [source](https://github.com/kendo-labs/knockout-kendo/blob/master/src/knockout-kendo-core.js#L236): `//utility to set the dataSource with a clean copy of data. Could be overridden at run-time.` So it is fine to override it. The only drawback what it has what I've mentioned that this is a global function which will get applied in every ko-kendo binding.